# Not display Front end

Tags: magento-1.9

I created Simple Hello world Module But it's not Display Front End

Also I can't Understand in test.xml can you please any one explain it

**app/code/local/Manoj/Test/etc/config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <config>
        <modules>
            <Manoj_Test>
                <version>0.1.0</version>
            </Manoj_Test>
        </modules>
        <frontend>
            <routers>
                <test>
                    <use>standard</use>
                    <args>
                        <module>Manoj_Test</module>
                        <frontName>test</frontName>
                    </args>
                </test>
            </routers>
            <layout>
                <updates>
                    <test>
                        <file>test.xml</file>
                    </test>
                </updates>
            </layout>
        </frontend>
        <global>
            <blocks>
                <test>
                    <class>Manoj_Test_Block</class>
                </test>
            </blocks>
            <helpers>
                <test>
                    <class>Manoj_Test_Helper</class>
                </test>
            </helpers>
        </global>


    </config>
```

**app/design/frontend/default/Manoj/layout/test.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <layout version = "1.0"?>
        <test_index_index>
            <reference name="content">
                <block type="test/test" name="test" template="test/test.phtml"/>                                
            </reference>
        </test_index_index>
    </layout>
```

**app/code/local/Manoj/Test/Block/test.php**

```
<?php 


class Manoj_Test_Block_Test extends Mage_Core_Block_Template{

        public function getContent(){

            return "My First Module";
        }

}
```

**app/design/frontend/default/Manoj/template/test/test.phtml**

```
<?php
    echo $this->getContent();
?>
```

**app/code/local/Manoj/Test/controllers/IndexController.php**

```
<?php 

class Manoj_Test_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action{


    public function indexAction()
    {
        $this->loadLayout();  //This function read all layout files and loads them in memory
        $this->renderLayout(); //This function processes and displays all layout phtml and php files.
    }

}
```

**Manoj_Test.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <config>
        <modules>
            <Manoj_Test>
                <active>true</active>
                <codePool>local</codePool>
            </Manoj_Test>
        </modules>
    </config>
```

Comment: Do you have a controller declared ?

Comment: Please post your controller too.

Comment: Check my updated question

Comment: add the files path too

Comment: updated.........

Comment: `app/code/local/Manoj/Test/Block/Test.php`   the file name must be capital as added in class `Manoj_Test_Block_Test` also check the error log for errors. and make sure your `cache` is `diabled`

Comment: Also please ensure that your theme is configured as `default/Manoj` in the backend. You're trying to access `/test/index/index` right ?

Comment: Sorry it's my mistake it capital letter only

Comment: Yes I configure in backend same way frontend access also sam

Comment: Is the module enabled in the `app/etc/modules/Manoj_Test.xml` ? Is Disable Output set to "No" under System > Configuration > Advanced ?

Comment: I chacked that also it's enabled only

Comment: Please post your `app/etc/modules/Manoj_Test.xml`. Also could you try moving both layout and template files to `base/default` folder ?

Comment: Updated.....................

Comment: Any chance when moving layout/template to base/default ? ANy error in the log ?

Comment: What if you replace `<test><file>test.xml</file></test>` with `<Manoj_Test><file>test.xml</file></Manoj_Test>` in your `config.xml` ?

Comment: 404 Page Not found

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after testing and changing in both file it start working

**`config.xml`**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <Manoj_Test>
      <version>0.1.0</version>
    </Manoj_Test>
  </modules>
  <frontend>
    <routers>
      <test>
        <use>standard</use>
          <args>
            <module>Manoj_Test</module>
            <frontName>test</frontName>
          </args>
      </test>
    </routers>
        <layout>
          <updates>
            <test>
              <file>test.xml</file>
            </test>
          </updates>
        </layout>
  </frontend>
  <global>
    <helpers>
      <test>
        <class>Manoj_Test_Helper</class>
      </test>
    </helpers>
    <blocks>
      <test>
        <class>Manoj_Test_Block</class>
      </test>
    </blocks>
  </global>
</config>
```

**test.xml**

```
  <?xml version="1.0"?>   
<layout version="0.1.0">   
  <test_index_index>   
    <reference name="root">   
      <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/1column.phtml</template></action>   
    </reference>   
    <reference name="content">   
      <block type="test/test" name="test" template="test/test.phtml"/>   
    </reference>   
  </test_index_index>   
</layout>
```

Comment: Thanks @Qaisar Satti can you please  explain this <test_index_index>

Comment: `test` is your module name and `index` is your controller name and last `index` is your `IndexController`  Action method.

Comment: Hey You know how to filer recent customer display first

Comment: you can apply sort by id `desc` the recent will display first
`$collection = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->getCollection()
   ->addAttributeToSelect('firstname')
   ->addAttributeToSelect('lastname')
   ->addAttributeToSelect('email')->setOrder('entity_id' , 'desc');`

Comment: But it's seller can you please check this http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/103747/collection-recent-customer